# Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, es6-promise

I am trying to use the finally method on a promise but I keep getting this error.

```
Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'.
```

I have looked up similar questions to this which have suggested adding "es2018.promise" to the "lib" array in tsconfig.js. This then produces the following error:

```
typescript error
        Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'esnext', 'dom',
        'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator',
        'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol',
        'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string',
        'es2017.intl', 'esnext.asynciterable'.
```

Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just tested on stack itself, it works. Consider providing a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?  Support for ES2018 wasn't added until 2.7: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20463

Comment: Just checked and its 2.6.2, I will update and check it's resolved.

Comment: Thank you! This has resolved it!

Comment: Hi again, my ionic app now compiles without throwing an error but I now get this error when it tries to run a code block using .finally(). "TypeError: this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(...).then(...).finally is not a function", any idea why?

Comment: @JJPell: Is `file` a FileReader instance? If so, then `readAsArrayBuffer()` doesn't return anything.. In that case you should actually be getting an error for using `then()` itself... use the `onload/loadend` event to do your job..

Comment: nah `file` is an instance of ionics file plugin which is basicly a FileReader instance but it returns a promise. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file#readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: I suspect that this is being caused by my tsconfig.json compilerOptions. Can anyone confirm if this is the correct settings `"lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext",
    ], "target": "esnext"`

Comment: If you are getting a runtime error on the `finally` call, then the promise implementation in your runtime environment does not support `finally`.  There's nothing TypeScript can do about that.  You can try installing [this polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.prototype.finally).

Comment: Thanks Matt, this sorted it

Answer (score 68):

For `TypeScript 3.3.3`, just add `es2018.promise` to your `tsconfig.json` - `compilerOptions.lib` config like this:

`"lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "dom", "es2018.promise"]`

If you use `vscode`, maybe you should `reload window` after adding this option to your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: I ran into this out of the blue. I didn't update anything for ages and I've been compiling a lot with no errors... Then suddenly this "finally" error today. I am using version 3.2.4. Just added es2018 to tsconfig.json and everything works again. 
Seems strange. But why es2018.promise and not just es2018?

Comment: @Jette `es2018` contains `ES2018.Intl`, `ES2018.Promise` and `ES2018.RegExp`. So if you just need `finally` feature, just add `es2018.promise` to lib.

Comment: Does it make sense to include several versions of ES (2015 and 2016 in your case)? I understand that you need at least one "full" library but I'm not sure why you'd want two. I am using `["DOM", "es2017", "es2018.promise"]` and it's working for me.

Comment: In `TypeScript 2.7`, you have to add `"esnext.promise"` instead of `"es2018.promise"`

Answer (score 8):

ES2018 support was not added until [TypeScript 2.7](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20463).  Upgrading to that version or later resolves this error.

Comment: I added `esnext` and only then it works.I'm on typescript-2.7.
With typescript-2.7 it doesnt work with `es2018`.
Will this support old browsers?

Comment: With old browsers you usually need polyfills.

Answer (score 7):

While TypeScript 2.7 might support it you need to target: "ESNEXT" in your tsconfig.json.

Which means that your code will probably not run in older browsers or node.js versions.

I'm using:

```
"@types/promise.prototype.finally": "^2.0.2"
```

```
import { shim as finallyShim } from 'promise.prototype.finally'; 
finallyShim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.prototype.finally as it seems to be an issue with ionic not typescript. I imagine it will be fixed in the near future.

Thanks to everyone who helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you yarn/npm install first, the error disappears after installation if you already have the `es2018.promise` in `tsconfig.json`.