# error TS2339: Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, jhipster

I am working on enhancing my Login component by using some JHipster generated services, but I've encountered a problem.

I am getting `error TS2339: Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'.` when I try to submit the login form.

Here is the code which generates error: **login.component.ts**

```
login() {
    if (this.validate(this.form)) {
        this.loginService
            .login({
                username: this.model.username,
                password: this.model.password,
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.redirectUser();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.authNoticeService.setNotice('The username or password is incorrect', 'error');
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.spinner.active = false;
                this.actionChange.next( this.action );
            });
    }
}
```

**login.service.ts**

```
login(credentials, callback?) {
    const cb = callback || function() {};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.principal.identity(true).then(account => {
                    // After the login the language will be changed to
                    // the language selected by the user during his registration
                    if (account !== null) {
                        this.languageService.changeLanguage(account.langKey);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
                return cb();
            },
            err => {
                this.logout();
                reject(err);
                return cb(err);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

I've tried to add returning type of login method from `login.service.ts` like that:

```
login(credentials, callback?):Promise<any> {
```

But without any success.

I've done some research and according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098456/9026582 the problem should be resolved with `typescript: 2.7.0`.
I have `typescript: 2.7.2` version, so I guess that it is not the case.

Maybe the problem is connected to callbacks in `login(credentials, callback?)` method?

**EDIT: original tsconfig.json configuration**

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079031/property-finally-does-not-exist-on-type-promisevoid

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Please read my whole question, as I've wrote that followed that topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finally` is part of the `es2018` spec. You need to either set your `target` to `2018` or you need to include the `es2018` lib.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
     ...
}
```

or

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "dom",
        "scripthost"
    ]
   ...
}
```

The difference between the two option is whether the compiler will emit JavaScript code compatible with `es2018` (ie it will not down-compile language features)  with the `target` option or whether the compiler just assumes the runtime features of the spec exist (as defined by the specified libs) but it will still down-compile language features to whatever target you specify (if you use `lib`)

Comment: Replaced: `"lib": [ "es2017",  "dom" ]` in `tsconfig.json` with `"lib": [ "es2018",  "dom" ]`, restarted the server, but no success :/

Comment: @rupertoss this should really be the issue .. could you post your current tsconfig ? What version of ts are you using ?

Comment: Edited the question and added original tsconfig.json files

Comment: @rupertoss with your tsconfig (with 2017) I get the error. When I change it to `2018` the error goes away instantly in vs code. Maybe you are not editing the correct tsconfig  ?

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working for me. It's just to lines of code in finally block so I added them in both then and catch. I know that it is not the nice solution but it works. Your answer seems to be clearly the right one, especially when you say that you've checked that. It just does not work on my machine.